# SQL oracle beginner questions

Tags: sql, oracle

Question1:
Do i have to use to_date while inserting date?

```
INSERT INTO some_table (date1, date2) 
    VALUES (to_date('2012-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2012-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Or can just insert as string? Will everything be OK this way too? I've tried and it worked.

```
INSERT INTO some_table (date1, date2) 
        VALUES ('2012-10-24',2012-10-24');
```

Question2:
What happens if i won't name columns that i'm inserting into? It works, but my question is if it inserts randomly now or it takes order of columns during creation of table?

```
INSERT INTO some_table 
        VALUES ('2012-10-24',2012-10-24');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 seems to only work with the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51049 says

> You can specify a DATE value as a string literal ... to specify a DATE value as a literal, you must use the Gregorian calendar. You can specify an ANSI literal... The ANSI date literal contains no time portion, and must be specified in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

However, it might work with time if you use the

> Alternatively you can specify an Oracle date value... The default date format for an Oracle DATE value is specified by the initialization parameter NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

For question 2, it uses the order at definition of the table. However you have to give values for all columns in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports Standard SQL date literals (since 9i).

It's **DATE** followed by a string with **'yyyy-mm-dd'** format

```
DATE '2014-05-10'
```

It's much shorter than TO_DATE and it's independent of any NLS settings.

Similar for timestamps:

```
TIMESTAMP '2014-05-10 09:52:35'
```

Regarding your 2nd question: It's the order of columns as defined within the CREATE TABLE.

Comment: but they learn a lot of old old stuff in our school... so they force us to use to_date and oracle:10g but thanks for some new info :)
but still you didnt answer question, could you please? :D Can i insert it just as a varchar even thought that its type is DATE? Can i then use all date functions on it, etc?

Comment: Well, Oracle 9i was released in 2000 :-)  Do they also teach DECODE instead of CASE and the old join syntax instead of JOIN? Even Oracle promotes the newer Standard SQL syntax over the old proprietary.

Comment: yes they teach DECODE but also teached CASE , is DECODE that much old/bad? <br>
and what is old join syntax? they teached us "join on" and "join using" , but also joining trought "where a.id=b.id" for better understanding i guess

Comment: DECODE is just old proprietary syntax, similar to a simple "valued CASE". Hopefully they don't teach the old Outer Join syntax using `(+)` instead of LEFT/RIGHT JOIN, you only need to know it when you read some queries written years ago, but for beginners this is just confusing IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You could even do it like this one:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM:YYYY:DD';
INSERT INTO some_table (date1) VALUES ('05:2014:10');
```

...but doing it like this is not recommended. Use `TO_DATE` or DATE Literal, e.g. `DATE '2014-05-10'` instead. It makes your life easier.